# Eloquent: Is chaining wheres (wrapped into functions) possible?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Project and Task models.

I want to do something like:

`$project->tasks()->active()->get()`

Where $project is a Project object, tasks() is a hasMany() relation, active() should be a function having `return $this->whereCompleted(NULL);`.

The question is if the whole idea is possible and where should I place the active() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Query Scopes : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

You just have to put this method in your `Task` model :

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereCompleted(NULL);
}
```